# roxy file manager Upload successfully but select image shows alert to edit conf.js

Tags: php, ckeditor, roxy-fileman

I have configured Roxy File Manager with ckEditor.
I have completed the installation,and it is working fine.File upload is also working fine the issue is with file selection.when I try to select image from server it shows me the alert message.
Here given two images
I don't know what needs to be change in json file.so Please guide me how to configure the json file

[Image-1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4QanMHja0bPUlktcGhkenI1bUk/view?usp=sharing)

[Image-2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4QanMHja0bPVjJjdGVqTk5GUmM/view?usp=sharing)

here is my json file
conf.json

```
{
"FILES_ROOT":          "",
"RETURN_URL_PREFIX":   "",
"SESSION_PATH_KEY":    "",
"THUMBS_VIEW_WIDTH":   "140",
"THUMBS_VIEW_HEIGHT":  "120",
"PREVIEW_THUMB_WIDTH": "100",
"PREVIEW_THUMB_HEIGHT":"100",
"MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH":     "1000",
"MAX_IMAGE_HEIGHT":    "1000",
"INTEGRATION":         "custom",
"DIRLIST":             "php/dirtree.php",
"CREATEDIR":           "php/createdir.php",
"DELETEDIR":           "php/deletedir.php",
"MOVEDIR":             "php/movedir.php",
"COPYDIR":             "php/copydir.php",
"RENAMEDIR":           "php/renamedir.php",
"FILESLIST":           "php/fileslist.php",
"UPLOAD":              "php/upload.php",
"DOWNLOAD":            "php/download.php",
"DOWNLOADDIR":         "php/downloaddir.php",
"DELETEFILE":          "php/deletefile.php",
"MOVEFILE":            "php/movefile.php",
"COPYFILE":            "php/copyfile.php",
"RENAMEFILE":          "php/renamefile.php",
"GENERATETHUMB":       "php/thumb.php",
"DEFAULTVIEW":         "list",
"FORBIDDEN_UPLOADS":   "zip js jsp jsb mhtml mht xhtml xht php phtml php3 php4 php5 phps shtml jhtml pl sh py cgi exe application gadget hta cpl msc jar vb jse ws wsf wsc wsh ps1 ps2 psc1 psc2 msh msh1 msh2 inf reg scf msp scr dll msi vbs bat com pif cmd vxd cpl htpasswd htaccess",
"ALLOWED_UPLOADS":     "yes",
"FILEPERMISSIONS":     "0644",
"DIRPERMISSIONS":      "0755",
"LANG":                "auto",
"DATEFORMAT":          "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm",
"OPEN_LAST_DIR":       "yes"
}
```

Comment: The linked images require authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write down the name of editor in conf.js

right now 
INTEGRATION : "custom" replace it with
**"INTEGRATION":         "ckeditor",**

Answer (score 3):

Check the Integration property

> **INTEGRATION** - Roxy Fileman is developed to work with CKEditor and
>   TinyMCE. For integration with CKEditor set this to "ckeditor", for
>   TinyMCE 3.x set "tinymce3", for TinyMCE 4.x set "tinymce4". For custom
>   implementation set  "custom", then fill "FileSelected()" function
>   located in fileman/js/custom.js - for more details see "Roxy Fileman
>   custom integration". The default value is "custom". This setting could
>   be overriden by sending URL parameter "integration" when openning the
>   file browser.

Please check declaration of `ALLOWED_UPLOADS` which asks for the file extenstion. Replace `yes` with `jpg png bmp` for example or better leave it blank.

> **ALLOWED_UPLOADS** -  Space separated list of allowed file extensions.
>   Set this if you want to allow  only certain file type uploads.  This
>   list is also checked when file is renamed. Default is "".

**Sample of ASP config.json:**

```
    {
"FILES_ROOT":          "~/writepermission_ok/media",
"RETURN_URL_PREFIX":   "",
"SESSION_PATH_KEY":    "",
"THUMBS_VIEW_WIDTH":   "140",
"THUMBS_VIEW_HEIGHT":  "120",
"PREVIEW_THUMB_WIDTH": "300",
"PREVIEW_THUMB_HEIGHT":"200",
"MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH":     "1000",
"MAX_IMAGE_HEIGHT":    "1000",
"INTEGRATION":         "tinymce4",
"DIRLIST":             "asp_net/main.ashx?a=DIRLIST",
"CREATEDIR":           "asp_net/main.ashx?a=CREATEDIR",
"DELETEDIR":           "asp_net/main.ashx?a=DELETEDIR",
"MOVEDIR":             "asp_net/main.ashx?a=MOVEDIR",
"COPYDIR":             "asp_net/main.ashx?a=COPYDIR",
"RENAMEDIR":           "asp_net/main.ashx?a=RENAMEDIR",
"FILESLIST":           "asp_net/main.ashx?a=FILESLIST",
"UPLOAD":              "asp_net/main.ashx?a=UPLOAD",
"DOWNLOAD":            "asp_net/main.ashx?a=DOWNLOAD",
"DOWNLOADDIR":         "asp_net/main.ashx?a=DOWNLOADDIR",
"DELETEFILE":          "asp_net/main.ashx?a=DELETEFILE",
"MOVEFILE":            "asp_net/main.ashx?a=MOVEFILE",
"COPYFILE":            "asp_net/main.ashx?a=COPYFILE",
"RENAMEFILE":          "asp_net/main.ashx?a=RENAMEFILE",
"GENERATETHUMB":       "asp_net/main.ashx?a=GENERATETHUMB",
"DEFAULTVIEW":         "list",
"FORBIDDEN_UPLOADS":   "js jsp jsb mhtml mht xhtml xht php phtml php3 php4 php5 phps shtml jhtml pl sh py cgi application gadget hta cpl msc jar vb jse ws wsf wsc wsh ps1 ps2 psc1 psc2 msh msh1 msh2 inf reg scf msp scr dll msi vbs bat com pif cmd vxd cpl htpasswd htaccess",
"ALLOWED_UPLOADS":     "",
"FILEPERMISSIONS":     "0644",
"DIRPERMISSIONS":      "0755",
"LANG":                "auto",
"DATEFORMAT":          "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm",
"OPEN_LAST_DIR":       "yes"
}
```